Merge and re-segmentize roads based on zoom level in PostGIS
I would like to draw good/bad roads on the openStreet map.
I split all road on small segments and color it depend on roads damage. When I zoom out the map I get huge list of segments and it makes the map slower.
The idea to fix it is to have S M L XL XXL segments and show it depending on zoom in/zoom out.
Currently i have a road segments table in db:



id
geometry




1
linestring(lg,lt)


2
linestring(lg,lt)


3
linestring(lg,lt)




The question is: is there a good way to split and merge this?
The idea was to write a recursive c# script to merge small segments make M L XL segments.
Is there a better way to do it?

You can melt the lines together and re-segmentize them according to target length defined for each zoom level. Here's an example on a bunch of 5-meter lines with lt between 0 and 60: demo
select zoom_level
      ,ST_AsText((
         ST_DumpSegments(
           ST_Segmentize(
             ST_Simplify(ST_Linemerge(ST_Collect(geom),true),0)
            ,segment_length))).geom)
from your_table 
cross join (values ('S',10) ,('M',15),('L',30),('XL',40),('XXL',60))
           as zoom_levels(zoom_level, segment_length)
group by zoom_level,segment_length
order by zoom_level;




zoom_level
st_astext




L
LINESTRING(0 0,0 30)


L
LINESTRING(0 30,0 60)


M
LINESTRING(0 0,0 15)


M
LINESTRING(0 15,0 30)


M
LINESTRING(0 30,0 45)


M
LINESTRING(0 45,0 60)


S
LINESTRING(0 0,0 10)


S
LINESTRING(0 10,0 20)


S
LINESTRING(0 20,0 30)


S
LINESTRING(0 30,0 40)


S
LINESTRING(0 40,0 50)


S
LINESTRING(0 50,0 60)


XL
LINESTRING(0 0,0 30)


XL
LINESTRING(0 30,0 60)


XXL
LINESTRING(0 0,0 60)



